# Health regeneration items not working?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-blades

When I found this item, I was quite pleased. But, after I equipped it, my health did not start increasing. What do I need to do?
[image]

Comment: It now seems to me that it is working in combat, but it is difficult to test, because I have to fight with all other related items off to be entirely sure, which in my case means: fight naked ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the game states in a few of the loading screens, health only regenerates on its own during combat! Outside of combat, you'll need to look for food, or use a potion to restore your health. Once you're back in town, all of your stats (health, stamina, and magic) will be restored as well.